# Easy way to resize image in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing

After data is loaded from filesystem, which model worth to use to resize image and return to client?

```
fs.readFile(process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR + request.headers['filename'], function read(err, data) {

    var w = request.headers['w']
    var h = request.headers['h']

    response.writeHead(200)
    // CODE TO RESIZE DATA
    response.write(data)
    response.end()
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ImageMagick:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick

Or other modules from npm:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-resizer
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-image
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/easyimage

Comment: any way to do this without a module?

Comment: Find very easy working sample code for image resizing using imagemagick. See here: https://jsonworld.com/demo/how-to-resize-image-in-nodejs

Comment: Note: This code has been unmaintained for a long time. Please consider using the gm module instead.
https://github.com/aheckmann/gm

Comment: I can really recommend the "sharp" package → https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize